# unoconv not working while trying to convert. throws Error: Unable to connect or start own listener. Aborting

Tags: ms-office, openoffice.org, docx, libreoffice, file-conversion

I am trying to convert docx to pdf using [`unoconv`](https://github.com/dagwieers/unoconv), but getting `Error: Unable to connect or start own listener. Aborting.` when I run `unoconv -f pdf 1234.docx`.

So, there must be some listener. I then started the listener via `unoconv --listener`.
I tried `ps aux | grep soffice`, and found soffice.bin.

So I tried  `unoconv -f pdf 1234.docx` again. It still gave me the same error:  `Error: Unable to connect or start own listener. Aborting.`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 11):

You have to kill all the soffice.bin processes before trying to use unoconv. I didn't have to do any "unoconv --listener" command.

Answer (score 3):

You need to kill all `soffice.bin` processes before executing unoconv

Comment: You may use this command in ubuntu: ```sudo pkill -f 'soffice.bin'```

Answer (score 0):

It fails with the error in the question if it does not find the LibreOffice personal configuration file, but it also creates them before exiting.
The second run succeeds.

You can reproduce the error but removing the personal configuration files, then trying to run unoconv:

```
$ rm -rf .config/libreoffice/
$ unoconv foo
Error: Unable to connect or start own listener. Aborting.
```

https://github.com/dagwieers/unoconv/issues/241

Answer (score 0):

Failing to start instance hints at the inability of the script to find the LibreOffice program.

Do this basic test:

1. Copy the unoconverter to "libreoffice/program" folder.
2. IMPORTANT: Go there and try to execute `./soffice` to verify that the soffice runs itself.
3. Now run unoconv with the version of python that shipped with the LibreOffice by typing `./python unocov  -f pdf 1234.docx`

You should see the converted file in the same directory now. Kill the soffice process and retry if it generates the same error.

Answer (score -8):

unoconv does not support .docx / .pptx etc.

You need to use the old document extension, which is .doc, .ppt.

A simple rename would probably solve the problem.

Comment: Misinformation here: although it's not perfect, it does support Office Open XML (.docx, .pptx and .xlsx): http://github.com/dagwieers/unoconv/blob/master/unoconv

Comment: Yes, it does support it - but like I said, it _probably_ would work by renaming the files to a regular .doc/.ppt